# Is there MariaDB or MySQL in XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

I've downloaded and installed [XAMPP 5.6.15 for Windows](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html).

When I click on "what's included?" it says it comes with `MariaDB 10.1.9`.
But in its root directory there is a folder `mysql`, but no `mariadb`.

Also when I execute:

```
echo $_SERVER["MYSQL_HOME"];
```

I get:

```
\xampp\mysql\bin
```

So I assume it still comes with MySQL instead of MariaDB?

Comment: Run `mysql` from the command line or your client (phpmyadmin?) and `SELECT @@version`. It will report your MySQL/MariaDB version. Or from the command line `mysql --version`.  If docs say it's MariaDB, I suspect it is. MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL, so the executables are often named the same as they would be in MySQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MariaDB is a drop-in replacement for MySQL so you will see some folders with `mysql` as name but MariaDB behind it. See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/ as well...

Answer (score 5):

I've realised the same issue on my Mac.
On the web site it says MariaDB is included :

[image]

A screenshot from the setup window before installation begins, it says MySQL :

[image]

At the slideshow shown during the installation, it said MySQL is included :

[image]

This screenshot is from the application :

[image]

And lastly, here is what it shows at the terminal :

[image]

I still think they should change what is shown on the GUIs :)

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely Mariadb. You notice that the prompt includes mariadb and not mysql when you start mariadb using command line utility. You start it just the same way you start mysql

Answer (score -1):

i think it is MariaDB 10.1.9 in XAMPP.