# why it write mariaDB instead of mysql and don't show data base even don't create new one

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

[why it write mariaDB instead of mysql and don't show data base even don't create new one[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpASd.png)

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpASd.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpASd.png in

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34880194/is-there-mariadb-or-mysql-in-xampp

Comment: Need to add a `;` after the SHOW DATABASES to complete the command.